# Como subir uma imagem a um ficheiro usando JSP

Tags: java, imagem, jsp, file-upload

Olá como estao? já peço desculpas pelo idioma, pois vivo no Uruguai.
Queria saber como e quais objetos do Java(especificamente JSP) posso usar para fazer um Upload de imagens para um ficheiro no meu Windows?

Eu tenho um campo `<input type="file" id="imagen"/>`

Obrigado

Comment: No link:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm  tutorial de como fazer.

Comment: Valeu pela dica!